# How to use GoodReads API by a command line script in windows?

Tags: api, command-line

How can I run the api for a website using the windows file explorer.

See https://www.goodreads.com/api/index#search.books

How can I try to use this API by double clicking a file? or executing a command line such as

```
GoodreadsSearchBooks.js "Foldername"
```

and it would print

```
ISBN: xxxxxxxxx
Found 12 books
```

The objective is to get the average rating of a book to add it to the folder of a book. For example:

```
Roald Dahl - Fantastic Mr. Fox (folder name)
GoodReads Rating=4.2.txt (file put inside the folder)
```

after running the script above.

The two APIs I need are as above and this https://www.goodreads.com/api/index#book.review_counts